# Operator overloading on classes themselves

Tags: python, operator-overloading, class-method

I feel like this code should work, but the second expression fails. Why is that?

```
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def __matmul__(cls, other):
        return "abc" + other


print(Foo.__matmul__("def"))  # OK
print(Foo @ "def")  # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'type' and 'str'
```

same for `__getattr__`:

```
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def __getattr__(cls, item):
        return "abc" + item


print(Foo.__getattr__("xyz")) # OK
print(Foo.xyz) # AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'xyz'
```

A solution is to use metaclasses

```
class MetaFoo(type):
    def __matmul__(cls, other):
        return "abc" + other


class Foo(metaclass=MetaFoo):
    pass


print(Foo.__matmul__("def"))  # OK
print(Foo @ "def")  # OK
```

Is this a bug in (C)Python?

To be clear, the question is why does `print(Foo @ "def")`   not work in the first example, without the metaclass?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're observing is not a bug in Python, but rather a consequence of how operator overloading and class methods are designed to work in Python.

In the first example that you provided, you have defined `__matmul__` as a class method. While this allows it to be called directly on the class (`Foo.__matmul__("def")`), it does not enable the use of the `@` operator with the class itself. In Python, when you use an operator like `@`, Python looks for the corresponding special method (in this case, `__matmul__`) in the class of the operand on the left-hand side. Since `Foo` is an instance of `type` (because classes in Python are instances of `type`), Python looks for `__matmul__` on `type`, not on `Foo`. Hence, you get a `TypeError`.

In the second example with `__getattr__`, a more-or-less similar concept applies. The `__getattr__` method is designed to be invoked when an attribute lookup on a particular instance fails. When you try to access `Foo.xyz`, Python looks for `xyz` on the class `Foo` itself, not on instances of `Foo`. Since `xyz` is not found and `__getattr__` is an instance method, Python raises an `AttributeError`.

In your third example, using a metaclass changes this behavior because the class `Foo` is now an instance of `MetaFoo`, and the `__matmul__` method is defined on the metaclass. So, when you use the `@` operator with `Foo`, Python finds `__matmul__` on `MetaFoo`, which is now the class of `Foo`.

When you define `__matmul__` as a class method in `Foo`, it is not being set on the type of `Foo` (which is `type`), but on the class object `Foo` itself. As a result, the Python interpreter does not use this class method for the `@` operator, leading to the observed TypeError.

Using a metaclass solves this issue because the `__matmul__` method is then defined on the metaclass, which is the type of `Foo`. Therefore, the method is found by the interpreter when using the `@` operator. This is consistent with Python's design, where the special method must be set on the class object itself for implicit invocations by the interpreter.

Comment: Thanks Bilesh. Yes your explanation makes sense. I think my confusion has been that I figured Python would go to the instance first (in this case the class Foo) before going to the type (in this case type).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @bilesh-ganguly`s answer, I think my confusion has been that I figured the interpreter would go to the instance first (in this case the class Foo) before going to the type (in this case type). This works for regular (non-operator) methods.

For example, consider:

```
class X:
    pass


x = X()

x.foo = lambda y: y * 2
print(x.foo(1))  # OK, prints 2
```

adding the method 'foo' works, even though that method is not in the type (X), since the interpreter first looks for the method in the instance.

But now for an operator:

```
x.__matmul__ = lambda y: y * 2
print(x.__matmul__(2))  # OK, prints 4
print(x @ 3)  # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'X' and 'int'
```

So I guess the interpeter will not look at an instance to resolve an operator (unless explicitly called by name), and will go directly to the type.

Comment: you are adding methods to this **particular instance** of `X`, any other instance of `X` will not have these methods, use `dir(x)` to inspect, You need to modify `X`: `X.foo = lambda y: y*2`, this is identical as defining it in the class